# Sampling Error - Basic Regression Model in Stan

Tags: stan

I am trying how to learn Stan, and doing some deliberately simple problems to get myself up to speed. I have got stuck very much at level 1, having tried to run a simple bivariate regression.

I have data of the following format

```
stan_data <- list("y"=y, 
                  "year"=year,
                  "N_obs" = N_obs)
```

The full data is pasted at the bottom of this post, out of the way.

Anyway, my stan code for a bivariate regression looks like this.

```
lm <- "data {
            int<lower=1> N_obs;      
            real year[N_obs];
            real y[N_obs];
            }
        parameters {
            real alpha;
            real beta;
            real<lower=0> sigma;
         } 

         transformed parameters{ 
         }

         model {
             vector[N_obs] mu_hat;

             alpha ~ normal(0, 100);
             beta ~ normal(0, 100);
             sigma ~ uniform(0, 100);

             for(i in 1:N_obs){
                 mu_hat[i] <- alpha + beta * year[i];
                 y[i] ~ normal(mu_hat[i], sigma);
             }
        }"


write(lm, file="lm.stan")


lm.fit0 <- stan(file="lm.stan",
            data=stan_data, 
            chains=1, 
            iter=5000)
```

First, I have a query. Why do we have the statement in the model block `vector[N_obs] mu_hat;` (instead of `real mu_hat[N_obs];` in the transformed parameters block)? It seems from a little Googling that this is what you need to do.

Second (and more seriously), when I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
TRANSLATING MODEL 'lm' FROM Stan CODE TO C++ CODE NOW.
COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL 'lm' NOW.
SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'lm' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Error : Error in function stan::prob::normal_log(d): Random variable is nan, but must not be nan!
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "integer" : NAs introduced by coercion
error occurred during calling the sampler; sampling not done
```

As usual, any help greatly appreciated.

The data in fact looks like this:

> stan_data
>   $y
>        42089728    9339536    9781184  138361088   30910448   30411792
>       629997056   21062368    1167006    7631744    6925444    5893008
>       35743680     -55904  116299776     966712     178152   19397504
>      101188992 1536242176   44078264    1243806  105937664   43202352
>       -4213172   40201728   84412544   16671128          0   19432968
>       44403296   89021120   33442736    5850532   68061664          0
>      86286272  636771072   65779408    6416524   25559184          0
>             0   11437649  128506560   26867136    1646992  -16684608
>       43974528    6812660          0          0    -906249   17730360
>       6571846  -14056304   -2317026   29722656   43035904   70388248
>       -202987   24308224          0   19598944   25241600   31093140
>     172198080   68365824  -15307088  345229424          0   91912288
>       6387084    6936104  362958976   10828080   34233728  465616896
>     185831488    4554222   14789792   19448168   27692960   88308096
>      75171552 -246307584   11228152    8361832    2265296  172424512
>     1182046720   22629408    1165429  348064512   77001792   11092408
>       84706848  -19970752   -2386432   66124424   19266104   72069984
>      14311872   -1680048     509040  188740112  318636288  170175680
>    -244937216   16264160    6017916     327072  159117760          0
>      8156479  320665728   36684736   17502416   29556064   47395008
>      12937934  168051632          0     892982   10329560    1355983
>      -4529648     -43117  -10704432  226641152   23704368   -3433973
>     -73329408          0    3594688   51327088   59915116  293390016
>     382384192  -12102624 -336263424          0  -24685504    -899952   10155976  218019584   48748112   30058752 1842414592   44083792
>      5092000   24174848   10985128   33436544  159885024   36513376
>     140204416   12631560    8951732   25929808  353803264 3143784448   60253136     702773  506841344   38420128   11721112   92972608
>     60845840   30016168   37990192   -6470864   78287520   21554528
>      29755168    3766984   35639136   26794784  583849280  267967488
>      37916960   11501600   22704880  133042624     513627    3389580
>     289430272   21665616   85471472   39646656  116267616  -13407846
>      15678080   27691000     682450    9635360     580544   16791136
>        793524   38486832  -79701376  -63242544    2160139  202091584
>           300   60001872  120758144   50716744   13548672  623414144
>      21202400          0          0   17696512   -5566584   -3197064
>    201575680   34187360   50923296 1267788800   28845072    1021406
>      20589376    5255816   19726800   43046336   84012320   93750016
>       1549232    4102708   20721248   36500736 5098330112  -20425392
>       781041  247644672   28292416   21682296   52508672   38884352
>      57993648     953560    1437008   81498304   86611584   23846608
>       5454052   37785760   99136512   58742016 1308937472   37354624
>      14447532   19370288   81054432  108383989    5834392  196654592
>     -37886048  199787840  -38083360  -19815904    1496112    7065456
>      30429000    -190947    3102040    5150997    6569152     711859
>      42429536  148236256   70894720    -888473   62231296   15503290
>     -17289808  106739712  -46661248 -185851136  602047616   15609200
>        940000          0

```
$year
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

$N_obs
284
```

Comment: Update to say, I think the problem may not be with my code. When I do an analysis on part of my dataset, selecting the first 150 observations, it runs fine. When I try to do it with the whole of my dataset it blows up. That said, it looks to me like my data is well-formed, so any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To your first query, mu could either be declared as a vector (as you have done) or a one-dimensional array (as you speculated about). In your example, it shouldn't matter. In general, vectors can be utilized for linear algebra operations whereas arrays cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/stan-users/fsM8GPG4cpM/YVedcWYcmW8J

In short, this is a bug in RStan that tried to convert the storage model of integer data into integer.  But here the integer is so big so some NA's are created.  Will be fixed in the next release.